# Cox PH with mixed effects - time to event and how to set up survival

Tags: r, statistics

I read through all of the questions similar to "how to calculate time to event/ time between events" and the documentation for Surv(), coxph, coxme. I still need help confirming if I've set up my data correctly. This represents my data:

```
library(data.table)
library(survival)
library(coxme)
snippet <- data.table(age=c(rep(74,3),rep(73,3),rep(69,3)),
                      sex=c(rep(0,3),rep(1,3),rep(0,3)),
                      year=c(0:2,0:2,0:2),
                      CHEM_376=c(0.036469233, 0.262701338, 0.120690616, -0.197499658, -0.231236627, -0.368920289, -0.106358638, -0.055245055, -0.141187835),
                      subject=c(rep(1,3),rep(2,3),rep(3,3)),
                      status=c(0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1))
```

I want to run cox proportional hazards regression with subject ID as the random effect (from package coxme), a chemical CHEM_376 measured at each year, some covariates like age and male. The following runs, but I'm not sure if it's correct:

```
coxph(Surv(time=year, event=status) ~ CHEM_376 + age + sex + cluster(subject), data=snippet)
```

Does the package understand that year is the year number when these observations occurred, not the time to status change? Do I need to calculate years until the status changes to 1 for each person? I'm not sure how to do that. Notice that year is not a posix date time format. Thanks for any help in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create Survival object with `Surv`, the `time` argument is an interval in number of years (or days, weeks, etc) between beginning of the observation and the time of the event. You can also provide `time` and `time2` arguments to indicate the start and end times for survival intervals.

The argument `event` indicates if the event was occurred: 1 is yes (a subject is dead), 0 is no (a subject is alive or censored- dropped from the study, etc).

Google "Survival analysis with R" to find multiple articles about this.

Comment: can you explain in the context of the coxme package? it does both cox PH and mixed effects modeling at the same time.